# Header file in C for the functions with strings

Tags: c, string, header

main.c is my piece of code that takes the header file test.h and my test.h and test.c files as follows. I am not able to compile and execute this. Where am I going wrong?

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

char test(void);

#endif
```

is my test.h

```
 #include "test.h"

  char test(void)
 {
   return "abcd";
 }
```

is my test.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

int main(){

   char z = test();
   printf("%s\n",z);
   return 0;
  }
```

is my main.c file.

Comment: `char` is  not a string (not to mention that to return a string literal as `char*` isn't a great idea for other reasons...)

Answer (score 0):

"char test(void);" 
should be:
"char* test(void);

"char z"
should be:
"char* z"

You are returning a char array (technically a pointer to the start of the array) from test() not a single char.

**Edit just compiled and it works**

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

char* test(void);

#endif
```

is the new test.h

```
 #include "test.h"

  char* test(void)
 {
   return "abcd";
 }
```

is the new test.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

int main(){

   char* z = test();
   printf("%s\n",z);
   return 0;
  }
```

is the new main.c file.